# How to make some setup work before ApplicationEvent listener in test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test, mockserver

I have a customized spring-boot-starter which will call some REST APIs when it gets a spring application event of `ApplicationReadyEvent`, so the configuration class is something like:

```
@Configuration
public class MySpringBootStarter {

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void init() {
        // Call REST APIs here
    }
}
```

Then, I want to test the starter using `MockServer` which requires creating some expectations before the test runs. The test class may look like as follows:

```
@ExtendWith(MockServerExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration
@MockServerSettings(ports = {28787, 28888})
public class MySpringBootStarterTest {
    private MockServerClient client;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEachLifecycleMethod(MockServerClient client) {
    this.client = client;
        //creating expectations here
    }

    @Test
    void shouldBeTrue() {
        assertThat(true).isTrue();
    }

    @SpringBootApplication
    static class MyTest {
        public void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Test.class, args);
        }
    }
}
```

But in fact, the expectations are always created after the `ApplicationReadyEvent`, viz., the `init` method of `MySpringBootStarter` class is called before the the `beforeEachLifecycleMethod` method in `MySpringBootStarterTest` class.

How can I make the test work, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `static` block initializer to run required code before SpringContext boots up.